# Cannot retrieve data from OData Web API if ID contains backslash

Tags: url, encoding, odata, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have an OData service with Web API 2 and the ID column (nvarchar, primary key) on the underlying SQL Server database table may contain backslashes. In these cases I get a 404 error.

I've tried encoding the character as %5C but it didn't work. Any suggestions?

```
This works fine:
GET http://mydomain:myport/odata/Users('SomeIdentifier')

This does not work:
GET http://mydomain:myport/odata/Users('mydomain%5Cmyuser')
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable double encoding on the server and change the '\' to '%255C' in the request URL.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have found is for the odata URI string to use custom encoding or place it in the body as a put or patch request.

```
        /// <summary>
    /// Replace character that mess up url literals in odata uri
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="search_words">Literal String to replace holder tags</param>
    /// <returns>Processed String</returns>
    public static string UnEncodeOdataUri(string search_words)
    {
        return search_words.Replace("[GREATER]", @">")
            .Replace("[LESS]", @"<")
            .Replace("[STAR]", @"*")
            .Replace("[EQUAL]", @"=")
            .Replace("[COLON]", @":")
            .Replace("[SQUOTE]", "'")
            .Replace("[SQUOTE]", "'")
            .Replace("[PERCENT]", "%")
            .Replace("[PLUS]", "+")
            .Replace("[FSLASH]", @"/")
            .Replace("[BSLASH]", @"\")
            .Replace("[QUESTION]", "?")
            .Replace("[POUND]", "#")
            .Replace("[AMPERSAND]", "&")
            .Replace("[DQUOTE]", "\""); 
    }
```